# how to bring back the dynamic input fields appended from JQuery when there will be validation error in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

i have a form where i add dynamic fields from jQuery, now when i submit the form (not with Ajax) and if there will be validation error, the fileds which are appended from jQuery are not reserved and lost because the page refreshes.

i do not want to add jQuery validation.

my code is this, i will add pseudu input fields for simplicity.

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
    <button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-3 mb-2 float-right"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        Add Row</button>
    <table class="table table-bordered align-middle table-hover text-center align-middle detail-table"
        id="Add_Expense_Table_id">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>value</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="Add_Expense_Table_id_tbody">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="name1" class="form-control" name="expense_details[1][name]"
                        value="{{ old('expense_details.1.name')}}"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="value1" class="form-control" name="expense_details[1][value]"
                        value="{{ old('expense_details.1.value')}}"></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my jQuery is,

```
<script>
    var numRows = $("#Add_Expense_Table_id_tbody tr").length;
    let counter = numRows + 1;

    $("#addRow").on('click', function () {
        let previous_counter = parseInt(counter) - parseInt(1);

        let dataToAppend = `
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="name`+ counter +`" class="form-control" name="expense_details[` + counter +`][name]"></td>
                <td><input type="number" id="value1" class="form-control" name="expense_details[`+ counter +`][value]"></td>
                <td><button type="button" onclick="DeleteRow(this);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        `;


        $('#Add_Expense_Table_id_tbody').append(dataToAppend);

        counter++;
    });

    function DeleteRow(that) {
        $(that).closest('tr').remove();
        counter = counter - 1;
    }
</script>
```

the fields which are appended from jQuery did not appear back when there is form validation.

Comment: they are not being rendered because they didn't exists in the DOM returned by the server. You have two ways: 1) send it though ajax and handle the response. 2) generate again the inputs after the response.

Comment: Thank you for the response
that i know they don't exists in the DOM, but i don't how to send it back when there will be validation errors.
i know i can send the form through ajax but i don't want to do that.

Comment: check this (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#redirecting-with-input) out. But you can't use validation as you are doing